# Why does $0,\bar{9}$ equal $1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, infinity, decimal-expansion

I am finding hard to understand why $0,99999..... = 1$

I have the following proof:

Let $x$ be $0,9999...$

then $10x = 9,999...$

So $10x - x = 9,999 - 0,9999$

$9x = 9 \rightarrow x = 1$

From a philosophical respective, it does seem legit to me that if the decimal form of the number is never ending, then, at infinity and beyond it "tries" to reach 1, so it's limit to infinity equals 1.

My objection is that:

Consider the set $S = \left\{  0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n \right \}$

What is the possiblity that from the set S we obtain the number $2$?

$P = \frac{P(a)}{P(S)}$ = $ \frac{1}{n}$

so from there we can see that the possiblity is very low, $0.000...1$ , which again we can consider to be $0$ since :

$ \frac{1}{n}$ = $ \frac{1}{\infty}$ = $0$

But again, if we accept that $P = 0$, then there is no possibility that we can select the number 2 from the set $S$, which is false.

Comment: Hey, you have a proof (and a real, valid and sound one, btw): who cares about philosophy now?!

Comment: What exactly are you implying?

Comment: That if you have a *mathematical* proof of a mathematical fact, any other consideration about its truthness belongs more to ontological, philosophical or whateverogical stuff, but not to mathematics anymore... *at least* for the time being.

Comment: If your proof doesn't seem entirely satisfying, then the next step is to delve into what exactly a decimal expansion means and what a real number really is.  Your probability argument can be clarified slightly to show that there does not exist a uniform probability distribution on the natural numbers, which means any argument which starts by assuming you have such a distribution is immediately dead in the water.

Comment: The actual proof that $0.(9)=1$ will depend on your exact definition of numbers and of decimal fractions. Some people define real numbers *using* decimal notation. For them $0.(9)=1$ by definition.

Comment: Doesn't $1 - 0.99999... = 0.000...$ which is zero?

Comment: @DanShved It doesn't fully depend on the exact definition.  If you have established certain properties of the reals, a proof can just use that property.  For example, if you have $x\geq 0$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$ you have $x<\epsilon$, then $x=0$.  Then, you only have to probe that the difference between $1$ and $.\overline 9$ is less than $10^{-n}$ for every $n$.

Comment: @Nick Yes, although a lot of people try to argue that it is $0.\overline 0 1,$ which is slightly nonsensical, although understanding why it is nonsensical requires a certain understanding of what a real number is that not everybody has.

Comment: I guess $0,\bar{9}$ equals 1 because the decimal numbers are infinite, so $0.\bar{0}1$ doesn't make any difference?

Comment: @Aaron I fully agree. My point is that the shortest, easiest way does depend on the choice of definitions.

Comment: @Nick: Every decimal place can be labelled by an ordinary integer that expresses how many places to the left or the right of the decimal point that place is. So riddle me this: in which place is the "1" in "$0.\overline{0}1$"?

Comment: @Hurkyl I have absolutely no idea...

Comment: @Nick: Bingo. The fact we can't answer "in which place is the $1$?" is a big clue that the notation "$0.\overline{0}1$" doesn't actually make sense, if we're trying to write down a decimal numeral.

Comment: I also think that any person who asks himself this question should acquaint himself with *at least one* definition of real numbers. If one relies only on the intuitive understanding, one runs the risk of ending up talking about meaningless things, like the "number" $0.(0)1$.

Comment: *There is no possibility that we can select the number 2 from the [infinite] set S , which is false.* - Why is it false ? :-) If you were one man in a million, or a billion, or -worse- an infinite number of men, and *The Woman Of Your Dreams* were to *blindfoldedly* pick just *one* man from this large / humongous / infinite multitude of men, what exactly do you think (realistically, not optimistically) your chances actually were ? :-)

Answer (score 5):

Even though your proof is perfectly valid, here is another one; maybe this convinces you more.

The sum of the terms of an infinite geometric series $a_n$ with first term $a$ and ratio $|r|<1$ is $$S_{\infty}=\frac{a}{1-r}$$

Hence, $$0.999\cdots=\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{100}+\frac{9}{1000}+\cdots=\frac{\frac{9}{10}}{1-\frac{1}{10}}=1$$

Comment: That looks interesting, thanks!

Comment: The proof in the question is *not* valid, because it implicitly assumes that $0.\overline{9}$ represents a number and that multiplication by $10$ produces $9.\overline{9}$ (which is equivalent to assuming that $0.\overline{9}=1$): $10x=9+x$ if and only if $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that $0.\overline{9}$ doesn't have a limit: it's just a single number.

However, we like to define decimals so that they can be used to represent real numbers. And, in particular, we would like $0.\overline{9}$ to be equal to the limit of the sequence

$$ 0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 0.9999, \cdots $$

It is *this sequence* that "tries" to reach 1, and it is *this sequence* that we talk about having a limit equal to 1.

But $0.\overline{9}$ is not a sequence: it's just a number.

---

You make a related mistake in your objection: you confuse the single set

$$ \{ 0, 1, 2, \cdots, n \} $$

for various $n$ with the "limiting" set of all integers

$$ \{ 0, 1, 2, \cdots \} $$

It is worth noting, however, that there are serious technical issues with the notion of a *uniformly* randomly chosen integer.

(Also "probability zero" doesn't mean "impossible". There are significant dangers in trying to use one's intuition about "selecting" randomly from finitely many objects when studying more general probability spaces)

Comment: So, practical reasons is the short answer then I guess..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem people tend to have with this concept is that we sometimes assume our number system is the exact representation of the numbers themselves.  We are, in fact, dealing with a system similar to $\mathbb Z_{10}$, where we roll over to 0 again in a particular position after reaching 9.  There isn't a representation for 10 in this system, but instead a 1 in the 10's place followed by a 0 in the 1's place.  That said, representing thirds in this system is difficult, so if we change the base from 10 to 3, we can get an exact representation of $0.\overline{9}$ like so:

Given $1_{3} = 1_{10}$ and $0.1_{3} = 0.\overline{3}_{10}$,

\begin{aligned}
  & 0.1_{3}\\
+ & 0.1_{3}\\
\hline
  & 0.2_{3}\\
and        \\
  & 0.\overline{3}_{10} \\
+ & 0.\overline{3}_{10} \\
\hline
  & 0.\overline{6}_{10} \\
thus       \\
  & 0.2_{3}\\
+ & 0.1_{3}\\
\hline
  & 1.0_{3}\\
and        \\
  & 0.\overline{6}_{10} \\
+ & 0.\overline{3}_{10} \\
\hline
  & 0.\overline{9}_{10} = 1_{3} = 1_{10}\\
\end{aligned}

Comment: Writing "0.3" would normally be forbidden in base $3$...

Comment: Yes, it is, I wrote that to help explain the concept.

Comment: I suppose I should expand this out to a system of additions rather than these aligned equalities.